# How could I play av1 encoded videos with these conditions in Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: video, vlc, av1

I have read [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1061908/how-to-encode-and-playback-video-with-the-av1-codec-on-bionic-beaver-18-04) and [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1196840/how-do-i-get-vlc-on-ubuntu-18-04-to-play-mkv-files) but still I couldn't play av1 encoded videos truely. Audio streams play correctly but videos are not.

I have installed apt package manager vlc version vetinari 3.0.8 and it shows this error:

```
main decoder error: Codec `av01' (AOMedia's AV1 Video) is not supported.
```

After it i have remove apt's vlc and install snap vlc but when I play an av1 encoded video my system crahses and none of tty's doesn't work. I forced to reboot my system.
How can I play av1 codecs with vlc or some other stuff?

Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS

vlc vetinari 3.0.8

firefox 72.0.1

gpu driver radeon

mesa-va-drivers is installed.

Comment: I wanted to see some AV1 videos this morning, too. Removing apt's vlc and install snap's vlc snap (`sudo snap install vlc`) worked fine for me.